# Defining a function with parameters and properties in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I've got a function that looks like this:

```
var myFunction = function (config) {
  var example = this.property; // just illustrating that we use `this`
}
myFunction.__reference = 'foobar';
```

Now I'm trying to write it in **strict** TypeScript:

```
interface ExternalScope {
  property: string;
}

interface ConfigObject {
  name: string,
  count: number
}

interface MyFunction {
  (XHRLoader: this, cfg: ConfigObject): any;
  __reference: string;
}

var myFunction = function (this: ExternalScope, config: ConfigObject): any {
  var example = this.property;
}
myFunction.__reference = 'foobar';
```

With the above code I get the following TypeScipt error:

> Property '__reference' does not exist on type '(this: ExternalScope:
>   config: ConfigObject) => any

The relevant portion of my `tsconfig.json`:

```
"compilerOptions": {
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "outDir": "./build",
    "allowJs": false,
    "target": "es5"
},
```

Comment: You haven't told TS that `myFunction` is an instance of `MyFunction`.

Comment: How do I do that? I tried: <MyFunction> before the function. But think I have something wrong, as that gives me more errors.

Comment: `var myfunction: MyFunction = ...` would be the easiest.

Comment: Just doing that creates more errors. Can you write a full example that passes checks for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps this can be of help:

```
interface ExternalScope {
    property: string;
}

interface ConfigObject {
    name?: string,
    count?: number
}

interface MyFunction {
    (XHRLoader: this, cfg: ConfigObject): any;
    __reference?: string;
}

var myFunction: MyFunction = function (this: ExternalScope, config: ConfigObject): any {
    var example = this.property;
}

myFunction.__reference = 'foobar';
```

Even though `myFunction: myFunction` creates more errors you need to assign it.

when you simply do

```
var myFunction = function (this: ExternalScope, config: ConfigObject):  any {
    var example = this.property;
}
```

typescript tries to infer the type of the `myFunction` variable and since it cannot see any `__reference` property in the assigned function, the inferred type does not contain it either.
Hope it helps :)

Comment: When I tried that before the original error was resolved but I got two more additional errors: `Type '(this: ExternalScope, config: ConfigObject): any' is not assignable to type 'MyFunction'. Property '__reference' is missing in type '(this: ExternalScope, config: ConfigObject) => any'`...  and I also get: `Subsequent variable declarations must have the same type. Variable 'myFunction' must be of type 'MyFunction', but here has type '(this: ExternalScope, config: ConfigObject) => any'`.

Comment: It's actually a little difficult to understand what the error is in your comment. As far as the `Property __reference' is missing in type` is concerned that was occurring because when you were defining the value of the variable `myFunction` typescript could not find  the variable `__reference` in the definition. In my solution i have declared that `__reference` is an optional variable hence that error will not occur. If you want you can copy and paste my code to [typescript playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/) and verify that there are in fact no errors

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice the additions of ? in the interfaces. Applying those worked. Thanks!